# Disable Close button in Install4J

Tags: install4j

I am creating installer using install4j IDE. I want to disable close button on both installation finish screen and uninstallation success finish screen.

[image]

How Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. Clicking on the window close button on a "Finish" screen is the same as clicking on the "Finish" button in the screen.